# var_export($entity) causes PHP Fatal Error: Nesting level too deep on AWS, but not on internally hosted ESX VMs

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, fatal-error

Trying to get AWS to run a drupal site. Part of the site is a large data import which runs daily. However as part of the process, when errors or warnings generate relating to the import data, the attempts to log the error run `var_export($entity)`. This results in a PHP Fatal error, derailing the import process, but only on Amazon AWS instances (tried small/medium 64bit) running Ubuntu 12.04.

Virtually identical Ubuntu/Apache/PHP versions used on our internally hosted ESX VM do not exhibit the same behaviour so we're hunting for the reason why. We'd rather not edit the PHP code, since it's part of a Drupal contributed module so while we're hoping the Feeds module maintainers might consider a safer route, we'd also simply like to know why there seems to be some restriction on AWS and whether it's configurable on the VM?

Comment: Do you have xdebug installed? You can change this in php.ini `xdebug.max_nesting_level`

Comment: Yes I've seen a few answers talking about xdebug, however I'm more interested in why what should be a high spec VM in all regards and seemingly identical software versions has this restriction over a VM with lower resources. I guess maybe I'll need to result to `xdebug` eventually, but there just seems to be some funny business going. Thanks though :)

Comment: Is the xdebug setting the same in both environments? Sometimes defaults vary from distribution to distribution. PHP as far as I know, would not result in this error itself. Its xdebug that is generating it.

Comment: xdebug package is not installed on either.

Comment: In that case what I would do is try to figure out what is different in each environment. You could dump the php settings `php -i` to a file and compare them on each environment looking for differences.